# What does "flood had made" mean?

Tags: word-usage, literature, contemporary-english

A yawl is in the Thames and then

> The Nellie, a cruising yawl, swung to her anchor without a flutter of the sails, and was at rest. The flood had made, the wind was nearly calm, and being bound down the river, the only thing for it was to come to and wait for the turn of the tide.

What does flood had made mean? Is the tide rising or ebbing?

Comment: Did you look up the word in a dictionary?

Comment: *7. To rise or accumulate: The tide is making.* From AHD. Everything is still, so there is no tide now. This is from Conrad, Heart of Darkness, 1899. You should expect to draw meaning from context with old texts.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat, but if the water is ebbing then couldn't they move with the water and get into the ocean?

Comment: Yes -- I would modify my comment: The yawl anchors. The tide has reached its peak and is now at slack. Since there is little wind, the yawl must wait until the slack tide turns to ebb tide, which will carry it down river (oceanward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sense of *make* in nautical jargon, meaning the flood or ebb tide has begun to flow or ebb respectively (OED sense 58a), or more generally that it is increasing. In this case, the flood has made, so either way, the water is rising.

Comment: If the water is ebbing then the water shouldn't increase rather it should decrease.

Comment: @kashmiri When the ebb tide makes, it decreases. When the flood tide makes, it increases. If the tide, unspecified, makes, you may assume it is increasing.

Comment: Thank you. It was quite confusing.